# How do I set this in actionscript instead of mxml

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, mxml

I'm working with some mxml that I'd like to see how it looks like in actionscript. It's a popupAnchor that just has a custom view called `HTMLWindow`. The custom view is basically nothing but an mx HTML component `<mx:HTML>`

```
<s:PopUpAnchor>
   <views:HTMLWindow id="htmlWindow" width="500" height="500" />
</s:PopUpAnchor>
----
<mx:HTML id="html" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

So I basically know how to make `<mx:HTML>` and `<s:PopUpAnchor>` in actionscript and not sure how to display the `<mx:HTML>` inside the `<s:PopUpAnchor>`.

```
var html:HTML = new HTML();
var popup:PopUpAnchor = new PopUpAnchor();
//how do I tell the popup to display the HTML object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PopUpAnchor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/PopUpAnchor.html) descends from DisplayObjectContainer, so...

```
popup.addChild(html);
```